# How to connect multiple windows in gtk+?

Tags: user-interface, gtk

I have created a window in gtk+ .in this window i am displaying some text and have button"next" through which i want to move to next window and my previous window should disappear.my new window should display something say,text.
Can someone tell me how to implement this? 
I am new to gtk+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to use `GtkAssistant` [Gtk2](http://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk2/2.24/GtkAssistant.html), [Gtk3](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/3.24/GtkAssistant.html), which is a widget precisely for the kind of interaction you are looking for.  Run `gtk-demo` in your system to check the example with the code.  It is likely you have it installed.

Also, you can check the code online in [Gtk repository](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/blob/main/demos/gtk-demo/assistant.c). (Check the version you want to view, either for GTK+2 or GTK+3).

Comment: Can u tell me how to change color of title bar

Comment: It comes with the GTK+ theme.  Although, you can try [gtk_assistant_set_page_header_image ()](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkAssistant.html#gtk-assistant-set-page-header-image) to set an image as header.  If GTK+3, you can customize it using CSS, with GTK+ might be a bit more tricky.